# Не закрывается меню в приложении

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь сделать приложение, пишу его из видео:
[Видео по которому делал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ug5tc7zMJsM&t=1174s)
Прошу обратить внимание на 19 минуту, там он начинает делать, и показывать что меню это закрывается, и предпринимает действия для его закрытия, я сделал всё с точностью как он, но, результат у нас разный, у него всё работает, у меня почему-то не работает.
Я склоняюсь к тому, что возможно у меня снова глючит студия, но, это не факт.
[Ссылка на проект](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/qEkI24wOPZ2EHQ)

Данный код, который он последний добавляет:

`<!--Пытаемся закрыть меню--> <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMenuExpanded, ElementName=home}" Value="False"> <Setter TargetName="gameName" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"> </Setter> </DataTrigger>`

Comment: Эм... Во-первых, приводите нужный код сюда, а проект как дополнение. Во-вторых, на 19 минуте он показывает, что у него не закрывается как раз это меню, потом идет некий эффект перехода, где он показывает оригинальное приложение, в котором меню сворачивается. Смотрите далее, как он это решил. И опять "делаю 100% как в видео!", ну не надо так...

Comment: Я думаю, этот вопрос лучше задать автору видео.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Реально, посмотрите, я сделал точно так-же как в видео, посмотрите в проекте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @aepot та там не получится, я так думаю)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вы мне уже как-то помогали, когда у меня не работал MediaElement, это решилось переустановкой винды, интересно просто очень, щас может опять что-то не работает... А у остальных работает..

Comment: И чего вы хотите, чтоб я посмотрел? Я вас попросил код, который относится к вопросу, разместить в самом вопросе, а вы дали ссылку (причем битую), на проект, где я должен искать данный участок кода и отлавливать там баг. Ну не делается так. Ваш вопрос сейчас можно перефразировать так: `Нашел видео, по нему делаю проект, но не получается! Гляньте, 19 минута, что я делаю не так?` Вам эта информация дает что-либо? Ну вот я глянул 19 минуту, я вам сказал, что не так и сказал, что дальше автор видео это исправляет. Больше, с предоставленной вами информацией я вряд ли чем-либо помогу.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Дико извиняюсь, исправил. Я так-же исправляю, как и он, но, после его исправлений, у него работает, у меня нет, хотя код идентичен.

Comment: Ну да, 100% ведь все правильно делаете, да? Еще раз, внимательно, посмотрите на [7:08](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ug5tc7zMJsM&t=428s), а также посмотрите окно вывода, да черт, даже в последней студии еще проще сделали, прям отдельное [окно привязок](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d85cX.png), которое прям кричит вам, а вы не слышите его)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Такой я валет, спасибо)